# function::target(): How does the template type work for lambdas?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda

I want to store a lambda expression in a function object, then retrieve its underlying function pointer. *For reasons I do not understand*, function::target() is a templated function that returns nullptr if the incorrect type is passed in (I'm working in C++11).

1. What type should I use in the template to correctly retrieve the underlying lambda pointer?
2. Why does function::target() require a template if function is already templated?
3. If the type of a lambda function is different from that of a global function, then why can both be stored into the same function object?

I have a vague understanding of how lambdas are expressions that result in temporary functions that are bound to namespaces and thus have a different type depending on which namespace they reside in. I have no idea if that impression is correct or how to apply it to what I use in the template argument. Any insight into what C++ magic is going on here would be greatly appreciated.

#### Relevant Links

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target

#### Code Example

```
void foo(int) { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    std::function<void(int)> a(foo); // well-defined global function
    std::function<void(int)> b([](int) -> void {}); // temporary lambda expression

    auto bar = [](int) -> void {}; // lambda expression stored in variable
    std::function<void(int)> c(bar);

    std::cout << a.target<void(*)(int)>() << std::endl; // 0x7ffe8e74ecf0
    std::cout << b.target<void(*)(int)>() << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << c.target<void(*)(int)>() << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << &bar << std::endl;                     // 0x7ffe8e74ecef

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that lambda object? You fon't know its type, which means you cannot assign it to anything or use ut in any other reasonable way.

Comment: If you need a plain old function pointer, why store a lambda in std::function in the first place?

Comment: When you assign a lambda to a `std::function`, the `std::function` does not store the function pointer, but the lambda object. Hence, you cannot retrieve the function pointer from such a `std::function` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a lambda expression is an object, not a function.
Every lambda expression has a unique but unnamed type.

You can recover an object from `c` since `bar` has a name; `c.target<decltype(bar)>()` returns a pointer to an object of that type (note that it's not a function pointer).

You can't recover the object in `b` since you can't describe its type.

Answer (score 1):

@n.m. and @j6t, your answers are on the right track for my intended use. I want to pass lambda expressions via function into long-lived sets, which necessitates the use of function. However, function lacks an operator==(), so I was hoping to use .target() to compare their underlying pointers.

Per @molbdnilo, I was unaware that lambda expressions were "objects", nor was I aware that std::function stores the lambda object itself, rather than a pointer to a "static" object living elsewhere (magic thinking, I suppose). So my hope of using target() as a makeshift operator==() between two function objects storing lambdas was flawed. I think I can come up with another strategy that should work. Thanks all.